# Round a tip with Javascript-Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to round the tip of this shape with canvas, I've tried with "arcTo" but I messed up. Thank you.

[image: The part I'd like to round]

```js
var my_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = my_canvas.getContext("2d");
var magnifier = 4
my_canvas.width = 27 * magnifier;
my_canvas.height = 45 * magnifier;
var x = my_canvas.width / 2;
var y = my_canvas.height / 4;
var triangleWidth = 13 * magnifier;
var triangleHeight = 25 * magnifier;
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(x, y);
context.lineTo(x + triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight / 2 - 1); // center-right
context.lineTo(x + triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight); // bottom-right
context.lineTo(x - triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight); // bottom-left
context.lineTo(x - triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight / 2 - 1); // center-left
context.lineTo(x, y); // top
context.fillStyle = "orange";
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
  This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

Here I prepared the [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/koba1/xr7kzpf3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a [quadratic curve](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_quadraticcurveto.asp)?

```js
var my_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = my_canvas.getContext("2d");
var magnifier = 4
my_canvas.width = 27 * magnifier;
my_canvas.height = 45 * magnifier;
var x = my_canvas.width / 2;
var y = my_canvas.height / 4;
var triangleWidth = 13 * magnifier;
var triangleHeight = 25 * magnifier;
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(x, y);
context.moveTo(x + triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight / 2 - 1); // center-right
context.lineTo(x + triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight); // bottom-right
context.lineTo(x - triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight); // bottom-left
context.lineTo(x - triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight / 2 - 1); // center-left
context.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + triangleWidth / 2, y + triangleHeight / 2 - 1) // quadratic curve
context.fillStyle = "orange";
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
  This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I make the tip of the curve touch the point "context.moveTo (x, y)"?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear where you want the rounding.

The example draws the original shape. Then again with whole top blunted. Last time with just the tip rounded.

```js
{
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var scale = 4
canvas.width = 27 * scale;
canvas.height = 45 * scale;
const x = canvas.width / 2;
const y = canvas.height / 4;
const triangleWidth = 13 * scale;
const triangleHeight = 25 * scale;
const left = x - triangleWidth / 2;
const right = x + triangleWidth / 2;
const mid = y + triangleHeight / 2;
const bot = y + triangleHeight;

ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineTo(left, bot); 
ctx.lineTo(left, mid);
ctx.lineTo(x, 0); 
ctx.lineTo(right, mid);
ctx.lineTo(right, bot);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();


ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineTo(left, bot); 
ctx.lineTo(left, mid);
ctx.arcTo(left, 0, x, 0, triangleWidth / 2); 
ctx.arcTo(right, 0, right, mid, triangleWidth / 2);
ctx.lineTo(right, bot); // center-left
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineTo(left, bot); 
ctx.lineTo(left, mid); 
ctx.arcTo(x, 0, right, mid, triangleWidth / 4);
ctx.lineTo(right, mid);
ctx.lineTo(right, bot);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();


}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, interesting solution! However the other answer solves my problem